# SQL Is Record In Date Range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, range

I need a sql query for my homework. 
The query must return correct results.

My wrong query:

```
SELECT RZ.* FROM TBL_HOTEL_RESERVATION AS RZ
INNER JOIN TBL_HOTEL_ROOM AS ROOM
ON ROOM.ROOM_CODE <> RZ.ROOM_CODE 
WHERE 
(CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(RZ.ARRIVAL_TIME,12)) <= CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('3/12/2013',12))
AND
CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(RZ.LEAVE_TIME,12)) > CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('3/12/2013',12)))
OR
(CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(RZ.ARRIVAL_TIME,12)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('3/14/2013',12))
AND
CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(RZ.LEAVE_TIME,12)) >= CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('3/14/2013',12)))
```

For example

```
room no : 1040
first reservation: 12 march  2013 -15 march 2013
second reservation: 13 march 2013 - 16 march 2013
```

I'm trying to do, if room have a reservation these date range, second reservation should not be done.

Comment: why you using `CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('3/12/2013',12))` not  `CONVERT(DATETIME,'3/12/2013')` ?

Comment: I found that code when i searched 'convert to datetime for sql'

Comment: But `CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('3/12/2013',12))` it's the same as `CONVERT(DATETIME,'3/12/2013')`. You probably don't need and these `(CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(RZ.ARRIVAL_TIME,12))`... I think your code can be simplified if you write format and type of your column `RZ.LEAVE_TIME`.

Comment: i did it but my problem is continuing

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many functions.  Date range queries are as simple as

```
where YourDateField >= TheStartofYourDateRange
and YourDateField < TheDayAfterTheEndOfYourDateRange
```

Keep that in mind as you figure out your assignment.

Comment: but i have two date range ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this hope it helps

```
WHERE 
CONVERT(DATETIME(RZ.ARRIVAL_TIME)) >= CONVERT(DATETIME('3/12/2013'))
AND
CONVERT(DATETIME(RZ.LEAVE_TIME)) <= CONVERT(DATETIME('3/14/2013'))
```